# Swift 4 - When sending POST request to localhost, my URLRequest sends the JSON data with the dictionary as a key

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, httprequest

Seems like a simple error, but I cannot resolve it for some reason:

```
let parameters = ["user_id":usernameTF.text!, "password": passwordTF.text!]
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
    print(parameters)
    print(jsonData!)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    debugTV.text = "\(parameters["user_id"]!)"+"\(parameters["password"]!)"

    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options:[])
        // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
        print(request.httpBody!)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        }
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print(responseString!)
    }
```

when see the NodeJS debug window, my request body is

```
req.body = { '[password: "test", user_id: "test"]':'' }
```

how can I convert the request data into a JSON object?

Comment: You need to set `Content-Type` header. `request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")`

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work either. It sends nothing in the request body using that line.

Comment: Do you really want to solve your issue?

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I said something incorrectly. Definitely want to solve the issue. When I added that line into the code for some reason the req.body no longer had any data in it.

Comment: OK, the description made something clear. Your server cannot handle JSON request. Try send your request as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: I have these two lines to HTTPHeaderFields:         
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
However still no change

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. _send your request as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`_ means two things **#1** you need `request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")`, **#2** set `httpBody` in the format `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you do not know much about it, search with `swift post application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.